# How to parameterize a string without making it lowercase in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is a nice method, `parameterize`, but it makes a string lowercase. So is there a way to parameterize a string without making it lowercase?

Comment: You can use gsub to replace or remove the special characters from string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the source of `parameterize`. So you could define a new method just change the last line `parameterized_string.downcase` to `parameterized_string`

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/transliterate.rb, line 80
def parameterize(string, sep = '-')
  # replace accented chars with their ascii equivalents
  parameterized_string = transliterate(string)
  # Turn unwanted chars into the separator
  parameterized_string.gsub!(/[^a-z0-9\-_]+/, sep)
  unless sep.nil? || sep.empty?
    re_sep = Regexp.escape(sep)
    # No more than one of the separator in a row.
    parameterized_string.gsub!(/#{re_sep}{2,}/, sep)
    # Remove leading/trailing separator.
    parameterized_string.gsub!(/^#{re_sep}|#{re_sep}$/, '')
  end
  parameterized_string.downcase
end
```

Answer (score 11):

In Rails 5 you can add the preserve_case option to parameterize.

```
"Ærøskøbing Brugs".parameterize(preserve_case: true) => "AEroskobing-Brugs"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're going for, but the `parameterize` method is intended to make strings URL-safe. [Capital letters are not safe to use in URLs.](http://wiredimpact.com/blog/never-use-capital-letters-urls/)

However, if you insist you could alway do this:

```
"AsDF".parameterize.capitalize # => "Asdf"
```